# How do I disconnect open connections to an Azure SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, restore, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am working on a process for restoring a database to my Azure SQL Managed instance which involves dropping the existing database and restoring a backup in its place (since Managed Instance doesn't support WITH REPLACE).

I am, however, running into an issue with disconnecting any open connections so I can do this operation. Users should be warned before updates take place, but we cannot guarantee no open connections.

Typically, I would do something along the lines of the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
--RESTORE HERE
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET MULTI_USER;
```

When I attempt to run something like this against the database in the managed instance, however, I get the following error:

> This ALTER DATABASE statement is not supported. Correct the syntax and execute the statement again. ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Is there a way to accomplish this in an Azure SQL Managed Instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RESTORE FROM URL in Managed Instance you can't even replace existing databases.

So either drop or rename the database before the RESTORE.  Both `DROP DATABASE MyDb` and `ALTER DATABASE MyDb MODIFY NAME = MyDb_old` will kill existing connections to the database.

Alternatively you can use the [Managed Point-in-Time Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/point-in-time-restore?tabs=azure-portal) to restore an existing database to a previous point-in-time.